# Google Chrome: Use --allow-file-access-from-files flag for MacOS

Tags: macos, google-chrome, chromium, google-chrome-flags

I'd like to run a study (local js file) in Google Chrome, but I can't play any sounds. Can anyone help me with this?

I tried disabling the new feature that causes the problem, but when I run the following code in my terminal, nothing happens. A new Chrome window opens and I can run the study, but the sounds still can't be played (I'm using a Macbook as you can see).

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files`

Here are the pages I got my approach from:

https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

It would be really cool if someone could give me a hint. I'm completely new to all this and have absolutely no clue what to do. Thanks in advance!

~ Merle

Comment: Does it work over HTTP? Do the devtools show an error?

Comment: Yes, the devtools say `audio.js:12 Fetch API cannot load file:///Users/merle/.... URL scheme "file" is not supported` and concerning your first question: I just put it on my server as an online study and that works perfectly, but I don't want to run it online tbh. :-/